# R Switch first part and second part of string at puncuation

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with columns:

```
names(data) = ("newid","Player.WR","data_col.WR","Trend.WR","Player.QB","data_col.QB","Trend.QB","Player.RB","data_col.RB","Trend.RB","Player.TE","data_col.TE","Trend.TE" )
```

However, I need to flip the first and second portions of each name at the period so it looks like this:

`names(data) = ("newid", "WR.Player", "WR.data_col", "WR.Trend", "QB.Player", "QB.data_col", "QB.Trend", "RB.Player", "RB.data_col", "RB.Trend", "TE.Player", "TE.data_col", "TE.Trend"`)

My initial thought was to try to do a `strsplit` and then somehow do an `lapply` statement to reorder, but I wasn't sure how to make the `lapply` work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a vector of names `v`, you could also try:

```
v <- c("newid","Player.WR","data_col.WR","Trend.WR",
         "Player.QB","data_col.QB","Trend.QB","Player.RB",
         "data_col.RB","Trend.RB","Player.TE","data_col.TE","Trend.TE")

gsub(
  '(.*)\\.(.*)',
  '\\2\\.\\1',
  v
)
```

Output:

```
 [1] "newid"       "WR.Player"   "WR.data_col" "WR.Trend"    "QB.Player"   "QB.data_col" "QB.Trend"    "RB.Player"  
 [9] "RB.data_col" "RB.Trend"    "TE.Player"   "TE.data_col" "TE.Trend"
```

And to directly assign it to names:

```
names(data) <- gsub('(.*)\\.(.*)', '\\2\\.\\1', v)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest next approach using a function to exchange position of values and `lapply()`:

```
#Data
vec <- c("newid","Player.WR","data_col.WR","Trend.WR",
         "Player.QB","data_col.QB","Trend.QB","Player.RB",
         "data_col.RB","Trend.RB","Player.TE","data_col.TE","Trend.TE" )
#Split
L <- lapply(vec,strsplit,split='\\.')
#Format function
myfun <- function(x)
{
  y <- x[[1]]
  #if check
  if(length(y)!=1)
  {
    z <- paste0(y[c(2,1)],collapse = '.')
  } else
  {
    z <- y
  }
  return(z)
}
#Apply
L2 <- lapply(L,FUN = myfun)
#Bind
do.call(c,L2)
```

Output:

```
 [1] "newid"       "WR.Player"   "WR.data_col" "WR.Trend"    "QB.Player"   "QB.data_col" "QB.Trend"   
 [8] "RB.Player"   "RB.data_col" "RB.Trend"    "TE.Player"   "TE.data_col" "TE.Trend"
```

Last output can be saved in a new vector like `vecnamesnew <- do.call(c,L2)`

Answer (score 0):

Arg0naut91's answer is quite concise, and I would recommend using Arg0naut91's approach. However, for the sake of providing a (somewhat) concise solution using `strsplit` and `lapply` with (perhaps) a bit more readability for those unfamiliar with gsub syntax, I submit the following:

```
names<-c("newid","Player.WR","data_col.WR","Trend.WR",
         "Player.QB","data_col.QB","Trend.QB","Player.RB",
         "data_col.RB","Trend.RB","Player.TE","data_col.TE","Trend.TE" )

newnames<-lapply(names,function(x) paste(rev(unlist(strsplit(x,split="\\."),use.names=FALSE)),collapse="."))
print(newnames)
```

which yields

```
 [1] "newid"       "WR.Player"   "WR.data_col" "WR.Trend"    "QB.Player"   "QB.data_col" "QB.Trend"   
 [8] "RB.Player"   "RB.data_col" "RB.Trend"    "TE.Player"   "TE.data_col" "TE.Trend"
```

as output.